# Transitioning on transform on pseudo elements causes elements to jitter in Safari

Tags: css, safari, webkit, css-transitions

I have found that animating `transform: translate` on an element's `::before`/`::after` will cause that element to jitter slightly while the animation is playing.

In this example, the text will move slightly after hovering over it. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get the issue to manifest 100% of the time. However, I was able to cause the bug to appear by zooming in/out to certain levels.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
}

div::after {
  content: "Hovering...";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

div:hover::after {
  transform: translate(10px, 0);
}
```

```html
<div>
  One
</div>
<div>
  Two
</div>
<div>
  Three
</div>
```

Comment: Don't worry about zoom...looks good :-)

Comment: @David If this only occurred when zooming, I wouldn't' mind it. But on my actual design, it occurs at most zoom levels.